# How to make a realtime PHP/ jquery realtime countdown script

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating an online game where after a button is pressed there will be a timer
for 100 seconds and then it will become available again

but i have no idea how to make this countdown in realtime without refreshing the page
here is my code at the moment

```
<?php

$gettime = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times WHERE username = '$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gettime))
{

    $gta = $row['gta'];
    $melt = $row['melt'];

}
?>

<?php
if((time() <= $gta) ) {
    ?>
    wait <? echo ($gta-time()); ?> seconds
    <?php
} else {
    echo "<font color=lime>Available!</font>";
}
?>
```

appreciate anyone who can help me

Comment: You have to write your code *client-side* -- meaning JavaScript.  jQuery not required for something that simple.  PHP runs on the server, so of course a page refresh is needed.  (Yes, you *could* do Ajax, but it wouldn't be reliable for something like a delay.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for setTimeout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout